# How to pass logged in user id to iframe url in Bigcommerce

Tags: javascript, api, iframe, getelementbyid, bigcommerce

I am using Blueprint theme in Bigcommerce. I need to pass logged-in customer parameter such as customer email or Bigcommerce customer id in iframe src url. I have tried like this `<iframe src="https://example.com?email=`%%GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerEmail%%`"></iframe>` but I uanble to receive the email parameter.

Comment: I have referred this document `https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/customers/current-customer-api#current-customer_logged-in-customers-javascript` i able to get jwt via browser but when tried with angular 7 I am getting error as "Invalid character: the string to be decoded is not correctly encoded."

Comment: whats' the response from the call to /customer/current.jwt?